# How to fill dynamic json value in drill down highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, drilldown

I'm trying to populate below json dynamically in drill down highchart, but data is not populating as expected.

I would like to fetch all user and put it in graph and in the drill down of each user i've to show **success,error,cancel, visit,enroll, uninstall**

I created rill down highchart with static data, please find the below link below:

This graph is my expected result:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jqueryb/ndfk7vgd/2/
```

**My JSON:**

```
var result=    [
      {
        "userId": "user1",
        "success": 1,
        "error": 0,
        "cancel": 0,
        "visit": 3,
        "enroll": 2,
        "uninstall": 0
      },
      {
        "userId": "user2",
        "success": 2,
        "error": 0,
        "cancel": 0,
        "visit": 4,
        "enroll": 2,
        "uninstall": 0
      },
      {
        "userId": "user3",
        "success": 1,
        "error": 0,
        "cancel": 0,
        "visit": 2,
        "enroll": 1,
        "uninstall": 0
      },
      {
        "userId": "user4",
        "success": 0,
        "error": 0,
        "cancel": 2,
        "visit": 4,
        "enroll": 2,
        "uninstall": 0
      }
    ]
```

I tried below code to populate value dynamically in drill down but no luck :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadChart(result) {
        var user_data = [];
        $.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)), function(idx, obj) {
            user_data.push(['{ name:' + obj.userId + ',y:1}']);
        });
        var test_data = '[' + user_data + ']';
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Basic drilldown'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Things',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: test_data
            }]
        });

    }
</script>
```

It would be very grateful if someone can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: build your data and pass it in correctly. you have to build your series data first. Also you have no built your drill down data yet.

Comment: yes I've not build drill down because my series data itself not coming properly, I tried to built series data dynamically but data not populating properly. If you ** test_data ** coming dynamically but i'm doing something wrong there :(

Comment: what are the errors that you get in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a php while loop, how do you echo the var results section below to use in the chart when the var results are from a query result?

```
var result = [
{
    "userId": "user1",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "cancel": 0,
    "visit": 3,
    "enroll": 2,
    "uninstall": 0
},
{
    "userId": "user2",
    "success": 2,
    "error": 0,
    "cancel": 0,
    "visit": 4,
    "enroll": 2,
    "uninstall": 0
},

etc...

];
```

Build your data correctly for highcharts:

When data is in json form, you can just use js basic objects to build it.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/x934L81p/1/

Build your series data like this:

```
    var user = {};
    user.name = obj.userId;
    user.y = 1;
    user.drilldown = obj.userId;
    user_data.push(user);
```

Then build your drilldown in the same loop:

```
    var drilldown_user = {};
    drilldown_user.id = obj.userId;

    drilldown_user.data = [];        
    drilldown_user.data.push(['success', obj.success]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['error', obj.error]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['cancel', obj.cancel]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['visit', obj.visit]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['enroll', obj.enroll]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['uninstall', obj.uninstall]);

    drill_down_data.push(drilldown_user);
```

Putting it all together:

```
var user_data = [];
var drill_down_data = [];

$.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)), function(idx, obj) {
    var user = {};
    user.name = obj.userId;
    user.y = 1;
    user.drilldown = obj.userId;

    user_data.push(user);

    var drilldown_user = {};
    drilldown_user.id = obj.userId;

    drilldown_user.data = [];
    drilldown_user.data.push(['success', obj.success]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['error', obj.error]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['cancel', obj.cancel]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['visit', obj.visit]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['enroll', obj.enroll]);
    drilldown_user.data.push(['uninstall', obj.uninstall]);

    drill_down_data.push(drilldown_user);

});
```